# Yandex Spellchecker API Returns Empty Array

Tags: python, api, spell-checking

I am trying to harness a Russian language spellcheck API, [Yandex.Speller](https://yandex.ru/dev/speller/doc/dg/reference/checkText-docpage/).

The request seems to work fine in my browser. However, when I use a python script, the response is empty.

I am stumped as to what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

def main():
    api(text_preproc())

def text_preproc():
    """ Takes misspelled word/phrase,
        “t”, and prepares it for
        API request
    """
    t = "синхрафазатрон в дубне"
    text = t.replace(" ", "+")
    return text

def diff_api(text):
    my_url = "https://speller.yandex.net/services/spellservice.json/checkText?text="
    my_headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36'}
    my_data = {
        "text" : text,
        "lang" : "ru",
        "format" : "plain"}

    my_uedata = urllib.parse.urlencode(my_data)
    my_edata = my_uedata.encode('ascii')

    req = urllib.request.Request(url=my_url, data=my_edata, headers=my_headers)
    response = urlopen(req)
    data = json.load(response)
    print(data)
```

The response is always an empty array, no matter how I tinker with my request.

Any insight into what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`my_uedata` has to be a part of the URL you send the request to.

Also, in:

```
def main():
    api(text_preproc())
```

You call `api()` but the function is not defined. I've used `diff_api()`.

Try this:

```
import json
import urllib

from urllib.request import urlopen


def main():
    diff_api(text_preproc("синхрафазатрон в дубне"))


def text_preproc(phrase):
    """ Takes misspelled word/phrase,
        “t”, and prepares it for
        API request
    """
    return phrase.replace(" ", "+")


def diff_api(text):
    my_url = "https://speller.yandex.net/services/spellservice.json/checkText?text="
    my_headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36'}
    my_data = {
        "text": text,
        "lang": "ru",
        "format": "plain"}

    my_uedata = urllib.parse.urlencode(my_data)
    req = urllib.request.Request(url=my_url+my_uedata, headers=my_headers)
    data = json.load(urlopen(req))
    print(data)


main()
```

Output:

```
[{'code': 1, 'pos': 5, 'row': 0, 'col': 5, 'len': 14, 'word': 'синхрафазатрон', 's': ['синхрофазотрон', 'синхрофазатрон', 'синхрофазотрона']}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your code is slightly cleaner, too.
It works perfectly now. My problem was my ignorance about sending requests. 
It was so frustrating, because I thought I had all the pieces and it just wasn't working.

Comment: We're all here to learn. If you find the answer useful, could you please accept it?